# PDFBox - Fill PDTextbox in PDF with word wrap

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

We have a requirement to fill a PDF with incoming data from vendor and one of field  is of type PDTextbox. Data that needs to be populated is a multi line and when we try to populate it using pdfbox API, all data is appearing in a single line and only initial part of the data is visible. Original PDF that we use to populate fields with incoming data for this specific field has multi line enabled. What is the best way to wrap text and populate it in PDTextbox? We have multiple PDFs and based on incoming data different PDF is selected and fields are populated. Here is code snippet.

PDDocument pdfTemplate= this.loadTemplateFromStream();

PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfTemplate.getDocumentCatalog();

PDAcroForm  acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();

acroForm.setXFA(null);

COSArrayList list = (COSArrayList) acroForm.getFields();

for (PDField field : list) {

```
  field.setReadonly(true);

  if (valueMap.get(field.getFullyQualifiedName()) != null) {

     field.setValue(valueMap.get(field.getFullyQualifiedName()));
  }
```

}

We are setting text value to field using field.setValue. What's the best way to wrap text?

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using?

Comment: We are using 1.8.10 Version

Comment: Please retry with 2.0.11. If it still doesn't work, please be more specific: does the wrap occur if the field is filled with Adobe Reader and you then jump to the next field?

Comment: Thank you for responding back. Our issue is text that needs to be populated is a paragraph and it is not wrapped. How can we wrap text and populate it? Original PDF that we use to populate text has multi line enabled for this field.

Comment: But after entering the text, should a tool that reads the field still get the text unwrapped, or in wrapped form (i.e. with newlines)? I.e. is this just about a wrapped display or do you want to know where to insert newlines in the text?

Comment: I'm asking because I had a look at the source code and multiline fields are wrapped by default. In 2.0. Don't know about 1.8.

Comment: 1.8 doesn't support wrapping text in multiline fields

Comment: Sorry for delayed Response. Upgrading to 2.0.11 helped fix our issue. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Moving to 2.0.11 fixed our issue. Thanks for the help.